# Mysql Group by delivers 2 options need them both but not together

Tags: mysql, date

So the code

`SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(august, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(august)) DAY) AS D 
FROM 
    Done 
GROUP BY 
    D`

gives me "2017-08-07" and "2017-08-14"

How can i get it to just give me them on their own?
Like i need both of these but a different times in my code

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code ..

Comment: <code>  
$sql = the code up there;
$pdoquery =  $pdo->query($sql)
foreach($pdoquery as $data){
print $data['D'][0];
print $data['D'][1];
}
</code>